# VB.NET - User Control Design (*) - "Save changes?"Always Shows, even if no changes were made

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a project that uses a user control.

[Designer Tab in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D3gO.png)

When I open the control it will automatically have the (*) in the tab, to indicate changes have been made.

Having a hard time searching for details on this one too.

Any thoughts?

[Save Change Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsJv.png)

I tried to remove all of the code behind the user control, but even without code behind it, the save prompt is set when no changes are made.

--
I re-created the control and noticed in the designer.vb a difference.

In both:
`Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer`

Only in the one with the issue: `Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()`

Comment: Maybe you should examine the files to determine what the actual difference is. I mean with a tool, not just with your eyes. It only takes one byte to change. This invisible shouldn't be happening but working out what actually is happening would be a place to start. That said, if you can just create a new file that doesn't do this, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Since the Form's `components` is initialized, it means that you have added a Component, e.g., a Timer, to the Form, dropped from the Toolbox. The `components` object is used to dispose of the Components when the Form closes. If the UserControl needs saving each time it's created, that means you have one or more Components (or Controls) that change property values at design-time and the value set is different from the `<DefaultValue>` of those Properties. Given the difference you have found, probably one of the Components